# Devise_for missing routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have two devise models, `Driver` and `Employer`

devise_for :employers, controllers: { sessions: "employers/sessions",
    registrations: "employers/registrations",
    passwords: 'employers/passwords' }

devise_for :drivers, controllers: { sessions: "drivers/sessions",
    registrations: "drivers/registrations",
    passwords: 'drivers/passwords' }

After a recent change I made, the devise_for :drivers has not been creating the registration routes:

`> rake routes:`

```
           new_employer_session GET        /employers/sign_in(.:format)                                employers/sessions#new
               employer_session POST       /employers/sign_in(.:format)                                employers/sessions#create
       destroy_employer_session DELETE     /employers/sign_out(.:format)                               employers/sessions#destroy
              employer_password POST       /employers/password(.:format)                               employers/passwords#create
          new_employer_password GET        /employers/password/new(.:format)                           employers/passwords#new
         edit_employer_password GET        /employers/password/edit(.:format)                          employers/passwords#edit
                                PATCH      /employers/password(.:format)                               employers/passwords#update
                                PUT        /employers/password(.:format)                               employers/passwords#update
   cancel_employer_registration GET        /employers/cancel(.:format)                                 employers/registrations#cancel
          employer_registration POST       /employers(.:format)                                        employers/registrations#create
      new_employer_registration GET        /employers/sign_up(.:format)                                employers/registrations#new
     edit_employer_registration GET        /employers/edit(.:format)                                   employers/registrations#edit
                                PATCH      /employers(.:format)                                        employers/registrations#update
                                PUT        /employers(.:format)                                        employers/registrations#update
                                DELETE     /employers(.:format)                                        employers/registrations#destroy
             new_driver_session GET        /drivers/sign_in(.:format)                                  drivers/sessions#new
                 driver_session POST       /drivers/sign_in(.:format)                                  drivers/sessions#create
         destroy_driver_session DELETE     /drivers/sign_out(.:format)                                 drivers/sessions#destroy
                driver_password POST       /drivers/password(.:format)                                 drivers/passwords#create
            new_driver_password GET        /drivers/password/new(.:format)                             drivers/passwords#new
           edit_driver_password GET        /drivers/password/edit(.:format)                            drivers/passwords#edit
                                PATCH      /drivers/password(.:format)                                 drivers/passwords#update
                                PUT        /drivers/password(.:format)                                 drivers/passwords#update
```

There is nothing unusual in the `routes.rb`, all initialisers are the same.

The change was accidentally running `rails g active_admin:install Driver` (a second time, I had done it correctly weeks ago). This generated this:

```
      invoke  devise
    generate    No need to install devise, already done.
      invoke    active_record
      create      db/migrate/20150330130706_add_devise_to_drivers.rb
      insert      app/models/driver.rb
       route    devise_for :drivers
        gsub    app/models/driver.rb
        gsub    config/routes.rb
      insert    db/migrate/20150304171112_devise_create_drivers.rb
    conflict  config/initializers/active_admin.rb
Overwrite /Users/Will/Google Drive/Driver Hunt/Code/driverhunt2/config/initializers/active_admin.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] n
        skip  config/initializers/active_admin.rb
       exist  app/admin
   identical  app/admin/dashboard.rb
      create  app/admin/driver.rb
      insert  config/routes.rb
    generate  active_admin:assets
rDEPRECATION WARNING: Support for Rails < 4.1.0 will be dropped. (called from <top (required)> at /Users/Will/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/bundler/gems/activeadmin-078f234288a1/lib/active_admin.rb:8)
ake db:migrate   identical  app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js.coffee
   identical  app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss
   identical  db/migrate/20150309131947_create_active_admin_comments.rb
```

What on earth has happened? Why has the devise_for broken?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. The solution was to run `rails generate devise Driver` again.

This creates:

```
  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20150330141801_add_devise_to_drivers.rb
  insert    app/models/driver.rb
   route  devise_for :drivers
```

I then deleted the migration. Fixed.

What exactly is going on in the background? What is `insert app/models/driver.rb` and `route  devise_for :drivers` doing? They don't seem to change any files in my app.